# Visualizing 28 different variables with 28 different colors?

Tags: visualization

[ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=qualitative&scheme=Set3&n=12) seems to be very useful in selecting a color pallet to represent factors that have up to 12 possible values.

I have 28.

Is it a horrible idea to represent 28 variables with color? If so, could you suggest an alternative visual indicator?

Currently I'm using the colors for column side colors in a heatmap shown below. As you can see, the Strain column is not very informative:

[image: Strain/Condition Image]

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use all 28 of them? You could use some dimensionality reduction technique and view them, if not necessary.

Comment: Interesting. Dimenaionality reduction on categorical variables? Can you say more?

Comment: An unsupervised method may be Self-Organizing maps. [Somoclu](https://somoclu.readthedocs.io/en/stable/example.html) is a great tool. It may also help with the visualization.

Comment: @kmace: Read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_analysis

Comment: Ideally, don't really on colour as your only method for distinguishing important information. [Colour blindness](http://www.colourblindawareness.org/colour-blindness/) is a thing.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Nice image, but what do I see here? Is it feature correlation?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I have come up with, I simply found a larger color pallet. The largest I could find was:

http://bl.ocks.org/aaizemberg/78bd3dade9593896a59d

So I merged `d3 catagory 20` with the first few from `d3 category20b` which was inspired from this heatmap tools [heatmap tool's](https://software.broadinstitute.org/morpheus/) source [code](https://github.com/cmap/morpheus.js/blob/331b63444284f7145fb8a2d773b54864a093250b/src/matrix/vector_color_model.js):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears your data is hierarchical. One option is to use a color hierarchy to help understand the relationships.

For example at the first split into two groups, you could have one group represented with a cool color (e.g., blue) and the other group represented with a warm color (e.g., red). Then at the next split in the hierarchy, those color palettes are split again. For example, the cool color is split into different shades of blue.

This would help with roll-up analysis. Instead of showing each individual level, show related groups together.